# Pushing copies to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am trying to push 15 copies of an object to a Firebase node which is an array. The object being pushed contains questionText and an answerText object. I didn't write the code for this particular part so I'm having a little trouble.

In firebase `quizText` is an array.

[image]

Below on line 125 in the methods section under the submitQuiz method I try to get 15 copies of the result into the `quizText` array but it is saying that `quizText` is not defined. What should I be doing differently?

```js
import db from '../db';

import ResourceCard from '../components/ResourceCard'
import FlashCard from '../components/FlashCard' // display info after submitting the answers
import Question from '../components/Question'

import { mapMutations, mapGetters, mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'quiz',
    components: { 
        ResourceCard, 
        FlashCard,
        Question
    },
firebase() {
    return {
        resource: {
            source: db.ref('resources/' + this.$route.params.resourceId),
            asObject: true
        },
    };
},
data() {
    this.$store.commit('resetForm');

    return {
        options: {
            lightResource: true 
        },
        showLearn: true,
        resourceId: this.$route.params.resourceId,
        passedResources: [],
        answeredQuestionsRes: [],
        resourceLink: window.location.href
    };
},
created() {
    let passedRes = this.$firebaseRefs['passedResources'] = db.ref('/users/' + this.$store.state.userInfo.uid + '/passedResources');
    let answeredQuestionsRes = this.$firebaseRefs['answeredQuestions'] = db.ref('/users/' + this.$parent.$store.state.userInfo.uid + '/answeredQuestions');

    this.$bindAsArray('passedResources', passedRes);
    this.$bindAsArray('answeredQuestions', answeredQuestionsRes);

    // Swap out buttons
    this.showLearn = false;
},
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        answers: state => state.quiz.answeredQuestions,
        submitted: state => state.quiz.submittedStatus,
        selectedCount: state => state.quiz.result.selectedCount,
        result: state => state.quiz.result
    }),
    score() {
        if ( this.resource.quiz === undefined ) return; 

        let isAnswer = (option) => option.isAnswer===true;
        let totalCorrectAnswers = 0;
        this.resource.quiz.forEach((question) => {
            totalCorrectAnswers += question.options.filter(isAnswer).length;
        });
        let selected = this.selectedCount;
        let incorrectCount = (selected > totalCorrectAnswers) ? selected - totalCorrectAnswers: 0; 
        let correctCount = this.result.correctIds.length;

        let amount = correctCount - incorrectCount;

        if (amount < 0) { 
            amount = 0;
        }

        return {
            amount,
            total: totalCorrectAnswers // total correct answer count - used to calculated messages
        };
    }
},
methods: {
    submitQuiz() {

        this.$store.commit('displayAnswers');

        let getCorrectAnswerText = () => {
            let result = {}
            this.result.correctIds.forEach(({quizIndex, index}) => {
                let quiz = this.resource.quiz[quizIndex];
                result[quizIndex] = result[quizIndex] || {}; // default to empty obj.

                // Trying to make copies here. 

                Object.assign(result[quizIndex], {
                    questionText: quiz.text,
                    summaryText: quiz.summaryText,
                    [index]: {
                        text: quiz.options[index].text
                    }
                });
            });

            return {
                [this.resource['.key']]: {
                    quizText: quizText(15).fill(result)
                }
            };
        };

        if (!this.options.testMode) {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                // delay to next tick, so we have latest computed values
                console.log(this.score);
                if (this.score.amount == this.score.total) {
                    // 100% answer
                    // Push specific resource object to Firebase under `/users/ ` + userInfo.uid + ` /passedResources` node ONCE score reaches 100% on submit. 
                    // console.log('100% answer', this.$store.state.userInfo.uid)
                    let passedRes;
                    // save answered quiz in passedResources
                    // update times passed if all questions answered or score = 100%
                    // console.log('incPassedResource', this.resource);
                    this.$store.commit('incPassedResource', this.resource); // update store
                    // console.log('after mutation', this.$store.state.passedResources);
                    passedRes = this.$store.state.passedResources;
                    this.$firebaseRefs.passedResources.set(passedRes);


                    // save answeredQuestion as text in user/uid/answeredQuestion/resourceID
                    let answerData = getCorrectAnswerText();
                    // console.log('answeredQuestions', answerData);
                    this.$firebaseRefs.answeredQuestions.set(answerData);
                    // no need to update store --> will be loaded into state in study component

                    // --> all questions answered - increment timesPassed on resource
                    let totalTimesPassed = parseInt(this.resource.timesPassed);
                    totalTimesPassed++;
                    // not working yet --> need to load timesPassed of resource, inc. & save back. or maybe use increment of firebase
                    this.$firebaseRefs.resource.child('timesPassed').set(totalTimesPassed); // todo firebase inc. would be handy here!
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
quizText: quizText(15).fill(result)
```

I think you meant:

```
quizText: Array(15).fill(result)
```